# Why are props not updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have this prop in a Flatlist and pass it down to AppleStyleSwipeableRow. It updates correctly in the FlatList when I mutate it but it does not update correctly in AppleStyleSwipeableRow. What am I doing wrong? Is it cause AppleStyleSwipeableRow is a class?

```
export default function SwipeableFlatList(prop) {
  console.log('this is prop in SwipeableFlatList', prop.data[0])
  return (
    <Animated.FlatList
      data={prop.data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <SwipeableRow
          item={item}
          index={index}
          navigateOnPress={prop.onPress}
          deleteRowCallback={() => prop.deleteItemById(item.id)}
          editModal={prop.editModal}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const SwipeableRow = ({
  item,
  index,
  navigateOnPress,
  deleteRowCallback,
  editModal,
}) => {
  return (
    <AppleStyleSwipeableRow
      deleteRowCallback={deleteRowCallback}
      editModal={editModal}
      data={item}>
      <Row item={item} navigateOnPress={navigateOnPress} />
    </AppleStyleSwipeableRow>
  );
};
```

output when I changed the name from "Why" to "Why does this not work XD":

```
this is in AppleStyleSwipeableRow {"__typename": "Key", "active": true, "code": "sdav1scmHSOWwh", "expiresAt": null, "id": "2ec51705-79e4-4352-9645-885ebea3c0b0", "name": "Why", "useCount": 0, "useLimit": 22}

 this is prop in SwipeableFlatList {"__typename": "Key", "active": true, "code": "sdav1scmHSOWwh", "expiresAt": null, "id": "2ec51705-79e4-4352-9645-885ebea3c0b0", "name": "Why does this not work XD", "useCount": 0, "useLimit": 22}
```